# NSArray with NSPredicate filter problems

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have a filled array with these data.

```
"2014-02-24 17:20:45.791 Info[5120:70b] Position 0: {
"0 : 0" = Ergebniss;
12 = Identifier;
"12.06.14" = Spieltag1;
"Brasilien : Kroatien" = Spielpaarung;"
```

This structure is supplied to me by a XMLParser. How can I read the string? ("Brasilien : Kroatien" = Spielpaarung or 0 : 0" = Ergebniss)
I tried it with NSPredicate. But get an error message.

2014-02-24 17:20:59.679 Info[5120:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "Spielpaarung"'
*** First throw call stack:

My Code:

```
NSArray *filtert = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.wmXMLParser.alleAktionen];
for (int i = 0; i<[filtert count]; i++) {
NSLog(@"Position %i: %@", i, filtert[i]);
}
NSArray *filtertNew = [filtert objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *attributeName = @"Brasilien : Kroatien";
NSString *attributeValue = @"Spielpaarung";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@", attributeName, 
attributeValue];
NSArray *result = [filtertNew filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you did not swap keys and values?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an array, you have a dictionary, so `NSArray *filtertNew = [filtert objectAtIndex:0];` should really be

```
NSDictionary *filtertNew = [filtert objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then, predicates are used for filtering, but you just want to access individual key values. So use:

```
NSString *value = [filtertNew objectForKey:attributeName];
```

---

If your aim is actually to filter the `filtert` array then your predicate is appropriate, but applied to the wrong thing. It should be:

```
NSArray *result = [filtert filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

(Though you might want to use `=` instead of `LIKE` in the predicate)